# WP-CLI get all posts from certain post type and taxonomy term

Tags: wp-cli

I am trying to select all the posts from certain post type and term in custom taxonomy, but what ever I try gets me just the list of all the posts in certain post type

```
wp post list --post_type=custom-type --fields=post_name,ID
```

This returns all posts in cpt `custom-type`, but say I want to list only posts in term that has id 49, I tried

```
wp post list --post_type=custom-type --taxonomy=custom-tax --terms=49 --fields=post_name,ID
```

But again I got everything. In the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/list/) it says that the arguments are passed to WP_Query, but how do I do a `tax_query`?

EDIT:

Ok so `wp term list custom-tax` will return the correct list of terms in the taxonomy. So I need to see how to use this to my advantage...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume we have a custom post type `movie` (slug) and a custom taxonomy `cast` (slug).

**1)** To find all movies starring *Emily Watson*, stored with the term slug `emily-watson`, we can do:

```
wp post list --post_type=movie --cast=emily-watson
```

to list all her movies.

**2)** To find all movies featuring *Elizabeth Taylor* **or** *Richard Burton* , stored with the term slugs `elizabeth-taylor` and `richard-burton`, we can do:

```
wp post list --post_type=movie --cast=elizabeth-taylor,richard-burton
```

We should at least get *Cleopatra (1963)* ;-)